# Overflow Error While Assigning Values From Resized And Offset Range To Variant In VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble with the below bit of code on line 8 `v = r.Resize(l).Offset(k).Value`.  For some unknown reason, I keep getting an overflow error; even for small l values (like 5k).  The range I'm working with is around 134,000 rows by 76 columns.  Would anyone happen to know why this might be the case?

```
Public Function RangeToStringArray(r As Range) As String()

    Dim v As Variant, sa() As String, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l As Long
    ReDim sa(1 To r.Rows.Count, 1 To r.Columns.Count)
    k = 0
    l = 2 ^ 16
    Do While (r.Rows.Count - k) > l
        v = r.Resize(l).Offset(k).Value
        For i = 1 To l
            For j = 1 To UBound(v, 2)
                sa(k + 1, j) = CStr(v(i, j))
            Next j
            k = k + 1
        Next i
        Erase v
    Loop
    v = r.Resize(r.Rows.Count - k).Offset(k).Value
    For i = 1 To r.Rows.Count - k
        For j = 1 To UBound(v, 2)
            sa(k + 1, j) = CStr(v(i, j))
        Next j
        k = k + 1
    Next i
    Erase v
    RangeToStringArray = sa
    Erase sa
    
End Function
```

Comment: Attempt to put a "debug.print" line in the while loop to check if it crashes the first instance or any iteration after it. Somehow, I think "Erase v" might have something to do with it as it deallocates dynamic memory. Also print the values for l and k, just to be sure.

Comment: What are the values of l and k when the error occurs?

Comment: The values for l and k when the error occurred were 2^16 and 0, respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly why this worked... but I just found a solution:

I selected the entire range that I was pulling in, ensured that all of the cells had a 'General' format, and then reran the subroutine.

That's it.  It worked.  Strange.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem but solved it by assigning range.value2 instead of range.value.

```
   v = theRange.value2   ' instead of v = theRange.value
```

This makes a difference for any date data or Currency but should otherwise be the same.

Answer (score 0):

### Range to String Array (`CStr`)

- Your code works fine on my end. It is (to me unexplainably) only about 10-20% slower than the following (on my machine). Give it a try, maybe there's a bigger difference on your machine.

```vb
Option Explicit

Function GetRangeStrings(ByVal rg As Range) As String()
    Const ProcName As String = "GetRangeStrings"
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = rg.Columns.Count
    
    Dim sData() As Variant
    If rCount + cCount = 2 Then ' one cell
        ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): sData(1, 1) = rg.Value
    Else ' multiple cells
        sData = rg.Value
    End If
    
    ReDim dData(1 To rCount, 1 To cCount)
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    For r = 1 To rCount
        For c = 1 To cCount
            dData(r, c) = CStr(sData(r, c))
        Next c
    Next r
    
    GetRangeStrings = dData
    
ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```